# Apache HttpClient remote query

Tags: java, php, mysql, apache, httpclient

I've got a server running with a MySQL database, I got a php file to get all the Tasks of a user (I have to give it the name of the user via POST), and then it returns a JSON with the result of the query.

In my application I'm using the Apache HttpClient library to make the conections, but I seem unable to find how to pass the user name that i wanto to the php file.

#### **Here's my PHP file:**

```
<?php
$encargado = $_POST['encargado'];

$host_name  = "falseHost";
$database   = "db";
$user_name  = "merlin";
$password   = "123";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$select = "SELECT * from tasker WHERE encargado ='$encargado' AND visible = 1 ORDER BY fecha";

$result = $connect->query($select);

$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;

}

echo json_encode($rows);

$connect->close();
?>
```

In my Java class I succesfully retrieved the result of a simple query (that dosn't need any POST args)

#### **Here's my Java class:**

```
public class Conector {


    static CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();


    //Devuelve un ArrayList con todos los username registrados
    public List<String> obtenerUsuarios() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

        List<String> listUserName = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://falsa.com/aplicaciones/f/select_users.php");
            CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

            try {
                HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
                String json = IOUtils.toString(entity1.getContent(), "UTF8");        
                Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<User>>(){}.getType();
                List<User> usuarios = (List<User>) new Gson()
                        .fromJson( json , collectionType);

                for(User user: usuarios) {
                    listUserName.add(user.getUsername());
                }

                EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
            } finally {
                response1.close();
            }


        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
        return listUserName;
    }
    
    public List<Task> obtenerTareas(){
        
        
        List<Task> obtenerTareas = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://falsa.com/aplicaciones/f/select_tasks.php");
            CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            try {
                HttpEntity entity1 = response1.getEntity();
                String json = IOUtils.toString(entity1.getContent(), "UTF8");        
                Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Task>>(){}.getType();
                List<Task> usuarios = (List<Task>) new Gson()
                        .fromJson( json , collectionType);

                for(User user: usuarios) {
                    obtenerTareas .add(user.getUsername());
                }

                EntityUtils.consume(entity1);
            } finally {
                response1.close();
            }


        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
        
        
        
        return null;
        
    }


}
```

Comment: Some starting material: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request

Comment: `HttpGet` in Java and `$_POST` in PHP are not friends